# NLog : Why is a config variable mandatory?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I find this puzzling and counter-intuitive :

Why this works :

```
LoggingConfiguration config = LogManager.Configuration;
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

While this won't (*EDIT : log files are not written to target file*):

```
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
```

It's funny to see how ready-to-use code snippets spread, while thorough explanations are so scarce

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but it might be worth expanding on "this won't [work]"

Comment: PS: there is now a `LogManager.Configuration.AddRule` which doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't checked the code but I guess that the property setter has some logic in it.

imho it should had been a method instead, or the configuration shouldn't have been exposed at all.

Comment: I checked NLog's source code and you're right. That's a tricky design and that's why it did'nt even occur to me, before you sensibly pointed it. I totally Agree this is confusing and such important behavior shouldn't be "hidden" in the setter. Getters/ and Setters are intented to priorly get/set, and this is a misuse as they are called just to fire the logic that it is embedded the setter. Thanx